# MvvmCross MvxListView Items Not Rendering on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, mvxlistview

I seem to be having a strange issue when binding an MvxListView to my ViewModel. I have triple-checked the ViewModel and can confirm that it is wired up correctly, as two other primitive types are binding correctly.

However, when I try to bind to an ObservableCollection (or an MvxObservableCollection), I get no items rendered in the MvxListView. I have followed the debug logs, and can see no MvvmCross errors, neither can I see any Android inflation issues.

I have tried various ways of raising propertychanged, as you will see in my code.

This is driving me crazy! Any help would be greatly appreciated. Perhaps I am missing something silly.

ViewModel:

```
private MvxObservableCollection<ReminderDto> _reminders;

    public MainViewModel(IApiService apiService)
    {
        _apiService = apiService;
    }

    public override void ViewAppearing()
    {
        Reminders = new MvxObservableCollection<ReminderDto>()
        {
            new ReminderDto() { Description = "Test" },
            new ReminderDto() { Description = "Test" },
            new ReminderDto() { Description = "Test" },
            new ReminderDto() { Description = "Test" },
            new ReminderDto() { Description = "Test" },
            new ReminderDto() { Description = "Test" },
            new ReminderDto() { Description = "Test" },
        };

        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Reminders));
    }

    public MvxObservableCollection<ReminderDto> Reminders
    {
        get { return _reminders; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _reminders, value); }
    }
```

MainView.axml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<MvxListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            local:MvxBind="ItemSource Reminders"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/reminder_row" />
```

Item Template (reminder_row.axml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/reminder_danger"
android:weightSum="6">
<TextView
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property to load a collection is `ItemsSource`, not `ItemSource`.
Replace this:

```
local:MvxBind="ItemSource Reminders"
```

With this:

```
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Reminders"
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Happy coding!

Comment: Usually you are able to spot these issues in the Application Output. It will complain that the binding expression is wrong and tell you whether it is the source or target that is wrong. In your case it would probably say something like target `ItemSource` could not be found.